# Alexa skill problem with response after response is already returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on an Alexa skill that requires a multi-step dialog where the user must answer multiple questions in succession. I'm trying to get started by adding a single slot prompt by checking if the slot is confirmed and returning a response with `addElicitSlotDirective` if it isn't:

Here is the entire request handler:

```
const isIntentRequest = require('../utils/isIntentRequest');
const sound = require('../utils/sound');
const loadUser = require('../utils/loadUser');
const loadWordByIndex = require('../utils/loadWordByIndex');

module.exports = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return isIntentRequest(handlerInput, 'NewWordPathIntent');
  },

  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const user = await loadUser(handlerInput);
    const { wordIndex } = user;
    const word = await loadWordByIndex(wordIndex);
    const slots = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots;

    if(!hasAnswered('NewWordEnglishAnswer')) {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak('New Word English Answer word ' + word)
        .reprompt('New Word English Answer word ' + word + ' reprompt')
        .addElicitSlotDirective('NewWordEnglishAnswer')
        .getResponse();
    }

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('You answered the new word english question')
      .getResponse();

    function hasAnswered(slotName) {
      const slot = slots[slotName];
      if(!slot) throw new Error(`Invalid answer slot: "${slotName}"`);
      return slot.confirmationStatus === 'CONFIRMED';
    }
  },
};
```

This seems to mostly be working. When this intent is handled, Alexa responds with: `New Word English Answer word evidence` which is correct, but then she immediately follows it with `There was a problem with the requested skill's response` and kills the session.

[image: Alexa dialog]

Why is this happening? If the response is being output, how is there a problem with the response?

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log to write things to the log and configure your skill to use Amazon's CloudWatch Logs to see the log. Even without you writing statements to console.log yourself, there will be info about the "problem with requested skill's response". 
Even without that, you can often get the information about the problem if you use the Alexa Developer Console Test tab to test your skill. It may show you something in the JSON Input or JSON Output that will give you a clue.